# Using sed to replace a string with the last character unspecified?

Tags: sed

I want to use sed (or any method) where I replace a string in a file.
The string is of the format "prv=x" where x is some integer. Is there a way in sed that I can designate this entire string to be replaced without specifying x?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; to replace only the first occurence of the string in each line:

```
sed -i 's/prv=[0-9][0-9]*/replacement_string/' inputfile
```

Or:

```
sed -i 's/prv=[0-9]\{1,\}*/replacement_string/' inputfile
```

To replace multiple occurences of the string in each line:

```
sed -i 's/prv=[0-9][0-9]*/replacement_string/g' inputfile
```

Or:

```
sed -i 's/prv=[0-9]\{1,\}*/replacement_string/g' inputfile
```

Using ERE syntax (if supported by your `sed` version), to replace only the first occurence of the string in each line:

```
sed -Ei 's/prv=[0-9]+/replacement_string/' inputfile
```

Or:

```
sed -Ei 's/prv=[0-9]{1,}/replacement_string/' inputfile
```

To replace multiple occurences of the string in each line:

```
sed -Ei 's/prv=[0-9]+/replacement_string/g' inputfile
```

Or:

```
sed -Ei 's/prv=[0-9]{1,}/replacement_string/g' inputfile
```

Comment: USing BRE you can also do `sed 's/prv=[0-9]\{1,\}/replacement_string/'`

Comment: Note that in there. It's the `-i` that is GNU specific and the least portable. `-E` is supported by GNU and many BSDs and is scheduled for inclusion in the next version of the POSIX standard. (the `-r` variant is GNU-specific and unintuitive/inconsistent so should be avoided IMO).